# Segmentation fault: 11, Absolute Beginner's Guide to C, 3rd Edition Chapter6ex1.c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

Can someone tell me why I am getting a Segmentation fault: 11. The code is from Absolute Beginner's Guide to C, 3rd Edition, Chapter 6ex1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

char Kid1[12];
// Kid1 can hold an 11-character name
// Kid2 will be 7 characters (Maddie plus null 0)
char Kid2[] = "Maddie";
// Kid3 is also 7 characters, but specifically defined
char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";
// Hero1 will be 7 characters (adding null 0!)
char Hero1 = "Batman";
// Hero2 will have extra room just in case
char Hero2[34] = "Spiderman";
char Hero3[25];
Kid1[0] = 'K';  //Kid1 is being defined character-by-character
Kid1[1] = 'a';  //Not efficient, but it does work
Kid1[2] = 't';
Kid1[3] = 'i';
Kid1[4] = 'e';
Kid1[5] = '\0';  // Never forget the null 0 so C knows when the
                     // string ends

strcpy(Hero3, "The Incredible Hulk");

printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid2, Hero2);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid3, Hero3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: and your debugging efforts?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: (1) Turn on warnings (2) Fix all warnings and errors (3) *Then* post your question if you're still having problems.  You forgot steps 1 and/or 2.  You have an obvious typo that should have produced a warning:  `char Hero1 = ...` should be `char Hero1[] = ...` or `char *Hero1 = ...`

Comment: Your compiler is the problem. Please post which compiler you are using and what options that are enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem *starts* with

```
char Hero1 = "Batman";
```

where `"Batman"`, (a *string literal*) is not a valid initializer for a `char`.

Then, next,

```
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
```

you pass a `char` in place of a `char *` (i.e., pointer to the first element of a null-terminated array), so it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:**

1. Enable compiler warnings and listen to them.
2. Change `char Hero1` to `char *Hero1` (*if you don't plan to modify later*) or `char Hero1[]` (*otherwise*).

Comment: Compiler warnings is not the problem; a non-conforming compiler is. That line violates the rules of "simple assignment", it is a "constraint violation" of 6.5.16.1. The compiler must give a diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is apparently broken. A conforming C compiler is not allowed to compile this code without giving you a diagnostic.

I would strongly recommend to toss out whatever compiler you are using and switch to a compliant one like GCC. Or if you are using GCC, configure it properly.

GCC set to be a standard C compiler `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` gives the following diagnostics:

- error: return type defaults to 'int'.
  You must declare a return type for main() in standard C, for example `int main (void)`.
- error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast.
  This line `char Hero1 = "Batman";` is not valid C, you probably meant to write `char Hero1 []`.
- warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int'
  This is caused by the above typo.

Comment: A conforming compiler is allowed to do anything at all so long as it produces a diagnostic for this code. Probably OP got a diagnostic and ignored it (or is using a web interface that suppresses diagnostics)

Comment: @M.M Yeah yeah fine, edited. Non-useless compilers don't generate an executable when there are constraint violations present though.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you. I am using gcc. I tried what you suggested "gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors". I however got the error: "clang: error: no input files". Any ideas?

Comment: @Lundin copying the error from my console revealed what I think to be the diagnostic you mentioned. It doesn't show unless I select the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

The two errors occurred when I compiled using  `gcc 6ex1.c -o 6ex1`

```
6ex1.c:10:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
6ex1.c:21:7: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an
      expression of type 'char [7]' [-Wint-conversion]
        char Hero1 = "Batman";
             ^       ~~~~~~~~
6ex1.c:36:47: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
        printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
                                       ~~            ^~~~~
                                       %c
```

I changed `char Hero1 = "Batman"` to `char Hero1[] = "Batman"`